# Look PP75 overhaul

Tags: road-bike, clipless, road

How to make a complete overhaul of Look PP75 clipless pedals? I already removed the plastic cap but I cannot remove the bearings. Does someone know how?

[image: Look PP75]

Also, where to get replacement bearings?

Comment: Generally speaking, replacement parts for pedals would have to come from the pedal manufacturer, or from salvaged bikes.  The exception would be bearings, if they are a standard size, but you don't know that until you open them up.

Comment: Pedals come apart (if at all) several different ways, depending on design.  Those appear to have a regular hex-shaped cap on the outside ends, that would come off using a standard wrench.  (But can't tell for sure.)  Once the caps are off there MIGHT be a nut (or two) under the cap, securing the axle.  You just have to puzzle them apart.

Comment: @DanielRHicks There is one nut and its already removed. I do not know how to remove/replace the cartridge bearings.

Comment: If they are cartridge bearings then likely they must be pulled/punched out.  Though look carefully for something like an [internal C ring](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/944/178/866/866178944_195.jpg) that may be locking things together.

Comment: Some LOOK pedals are designed to be taken apart and reassembled. Others must be replaced when worn. Check their website!

Comment: @DanielRHicks But if I pull them out, don't I have to replace them immediately? I've heard these type of bearings are for one-time use only.

Comment: @Carel Did you? These pedals are cca. 30 years old! I haven't found documentation for them anywhere, including their website.

Comment: The stated question is how to remove.  If the bearings are one time use then why are you trying to overhaul?

Comment: @Paparazzi The question is also where to get replacement bearings. I don't know if they are one-time use. That's why i'm asking. I don't want to destroy these pedals, they mean a lot to me.

Comment: Well, we can't help you much more without actually seeing the pedals, or at least some very good closeup pictures of the area under the caps.  Why don't you just take them to a bike shop?  Or, if they mean so much to you, put them in a display case and buy new pedals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some experience overhauling pedals like those.  First and foremost, some pedals are not made to be rebuilt, and you may destroy them getting them apart.

You may need to (carefully) clamp the pedal body and (carefully, again) use a punch and hammer on the axle to push out the "crank side" bearing and axle, then you can use a drift or punch to push the bearing out of the non-crank side, if there is one.

Something to remember, not all pedals use actual sealed bearings on both sides, some may use a DU sleeve bearing or bushing one side, and some may also use non-standard or hard-to-source needle bearings.  If they are a "standard" bearing, it's entirely possible to rebuild.  But what constitutes a standard bearing for your area and how involved you want to get is up to you.

If you got 30+ years of use out of those pedals as you say in the comments, it may be time to hang them up and get a shiny new set of LOOKs.

Comment: Thank you! I was almost 100% to hammer out the axle and that's what I'm afraid of. The bearings will surely be destroyed in the process (they are sealed I checked). I have new pedals